# Android-Broadcast Receiver and Intent Filter

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am new to android platform.please help me out how the Broadcast Receiver and Intent Filter   behaves in android.please explain in simple line or with example.thanks in advance...

Comment: Might be a good idea to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/366916/bharathi and accept answers on your recent questions.

Answer (score 20):

A broadcast receiver is a class in your Android project which is responsible to receive all intents, which are sent by other activities by using `android.content.ContextWreapper.sendBroadcast(Intent intent)`

In the manifest file of you receicving activity, you have to declare which is your broadcast receiver class, for example:

```
<receiver android:name="xyz.games.pacman.network.MessageListener">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="xyz.games.pacman.controller.BROADCAST" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As you can see, you also define the intent filter here, that is, which intents should be received by the broadcas receiver.

Then you have to define a class which extends BroadcastReceiver. This is the class you defined in the manifest file:

```
public class MessageListener extends BroadcastReceiver {


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
}
```

Here, all intents which are passed through the filter are received and you can access them using the parameter passed in the method call.

Comment: It's just the package he used as an example

Answer (score 15):

A BroadcastReceiver can be registered in two ways: `dynamic` or `static`. Static is nothing but declaring the action through an `intent-filter` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to register a new [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)  class. Dynamic is registering the receiver from within another class. An `intent-filter` determines which action should be received.

To create a BroadcastReceiver, you have to extend the BroadcastReceiver class and override `onReceive(Context,Intent)` method. Here you can check the incoming intent with `Intent.getAction()` and execute code accordingly.

As a new class, static would be

```
public class Reciever1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        String str = intent.getAction();
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("HELLO1")) {
            Log.d("Abrar", "reciever....");             
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {                     
                    Log.d("Abrar", "reciever....");
                    System.out.println("Abrar");                        
                }
            }.start();                          
        }
```

or, if placed inside an existing class, it is called dynamically with

```
intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("HELLO1");

//---register the receiver---
registerReceiver(new Reciever1(), intentFilter);
```

Comment: How can I do it between 2 devices, for example send some data from one to the another device? What should I define??

Comment: @JPerk you would need to handle the connection, but then you could define a custom intent to receive the data. There is a decent chance you would not be using an existing system intent to receive custom data or would not want to handle the default data it usually contains.

Answer (score 2):

`BroadcastReceiver` : 'Gateway' with which your app tells to Android OS that, your app is interested in receiving information.

`Intent-Filter` : Works with `BroadcastReceiver` and tells the 'What' information it is interested to receive in. For example, your app wants to receive information on Battery level.

Comment: is it better to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver instead of BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: FYI WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated.