# broadcast receiver for android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON

Tags: android, camera

I have an android application in which I take a photo.For that I'm building my own camera using a `surfaceview`.In this state of the application, the user has to touch the `screen/surfaceview` in order to take a picture.

Also the phone has a button which also the user to open its camera, the default one...which has nothing to do with my app.

What I wonder- is there any posibility for me to have a listener to that hardware button in my android application and to customize its behaviour there!

I repeat-the button I'm talking about is the `hardware button` that lies on the left edge of the phone.

EDIT:I understand that this is what I'm looking for `android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON`.Can someone provide a solid example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George take a look at:

[broadcast receiver for ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176402/broadcast-receiver-for-action-camera-button-never-gets-called)

and
[Android-Broadcast Receiver and Intent Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183756/android-broadcast-receiver-and-intent-filter)

and
[My BroadcastReceiver is not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED intent after my N1 boots. Help Please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935321/my-broadcastreceiver-is-not-receiving-the-boot-completed-intent-after-my-n1-boots)

You get the picture - use the search :-)

Basically you need a:

> Broadcast Reciever
>
> Declare this is your manifest
>
> Deal with the result

Comment: Yes but it gives you 90% of the code to make it work. Now look at the other links. Add it all together you have your answer :-)