# broadcast receiver for ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON never gets called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have an app in android in which I wanna take a photo when physical hardware button for camera gets pressed.I registered an intent  for this type of action but my broadcast receiver never gets called.

Here is how I did it:

class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class Adisor extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) != null) {
            // prevent the camera app from opening
            abortBroadcast();
            System.out.println("HEY");
            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is where I register my receiver to listen for actions:

```
protected void onResume() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    drb = new Adisor();
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(
      "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"
    );
    registerReceiver(drb, i);
}
```

And in my manifest file I have this:

```
<activity android:name=".TakePhoto" />
<receiver android:name=".Adisor" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000">         
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>            
</receiver>
```

The name of the activity in which I'm doing all this is:`TakePhoto`.My question is why my `onReceive()` method never gets called!

Neither this:

```
System.out.println("HEY");
```

appears in my logcat or the method

```
System.out.println("HEY");
mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallbacmPictureCallback);
```

gets called!
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen if it goes into the Broadcast receiver outside of the if()

Comment: I tried with a System.out.println() and there is nothing displayed.....I tried outside if()...what could be wrong?

Comment: please help me also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989221/how-to-get-camera-click-event-with-the-help-of-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either have the receiver registered in the manifest or register programmatically. Remove the `registerReceiver()` call from the `onResume` method.

Edit:

Add these to your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: And where should it be registered.Can u provide a working piece of code, please?

Comment: Putting the receiver in your manifest, registers it by default. Dont need to register programmatically. Just remove it from onResume.

Comment: @user7777777777 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2806/discussion-between-gabrielle-and-user7777777777)

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter should never have a priority of 10000. The maximum allowed for user applications is 999.

See [setPriority(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29) on the AndroidDev website.

Answer (score 0):

For opening the only the camera of your application you can use intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```