# Take new picture action on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to listen take picture action.
I use below code:

```
<receiver
android:name="CameraButtonActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"
        />
        <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
        />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>    




 public class CameraButtonActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
     static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON";

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
             System.out.println("Take picture");
         }
     }
 }
```

But it seems not works.
How can I arrive the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the action

```
public static final String ACTION_NEW_PICTURE
```

This is a Broadcast Action which is fired when a new picture is taken by the camera, and the entry of the picture has been added to the media store. getData() is URI of the picture.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE"

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176402/broadcast-receiver-for-action-camera-button-never-gets-called)  of the same question.

Hope this helps

Comment: I try to replace 'android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON' with 'android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE', but it seems not works.

Comment: Have you added the permission for hardware camera ?