# Sending alarm broadcast to a dynamically registered receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an anonymous class broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateStuff();
    }
};
```

I register it and create a pending intent:

Creating pending intent and registering the receiver

```
context.registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, new IntentFilter());
Intent intent = new Intent(context, mMyReceiver.getClass());
mMyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And set alarm (in `update stuff`'):

```
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, next, mMyIntent);
```

The intent is never delivered to the receiver. The alarm is set and targets receiver `MyClass$1` (which is the only anon class in the parent class). The alarm fires, but the receiver doesn't receive the intent. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe you'll have to use an implicit Intent for this; e.g., by specifying an action for the Intent and Filter. IIRC, dynamically registered Receivers don't work with explicit Intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://onemikro2nd.blogspot.com/2013/09/darker-corners-of-android.html

I think that is not possible. I have not tried it myself but was rather looking around to see if that was possible and found above link.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and misleading.  It is certainly possible to create an alarm with a PendingIntent and have it delivered to a broadcastreceiver.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183756/android-broadcast-receiver-and-intent-filter

Answer (score 1):

The comment is correct!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, mMyReceiver.getClass());
```

in this line you are using an implicit intent, just replace it with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must either declare the receiver in your manifest file, along with an "action" filter, or you must include the action in the "IntentFilter" which you created when dynamically registering your receiver.  Your code, as shown, creates an empty IntentFilter that will not match ANY intents.

Then, when creating your PendingIntent for your alarm, you must set the Intent's action to match the one that you placed in your filter.

This is not about implicit/explicit intents, as some of the other answers seem to suggest.  Implicit intents should be used ONLY when you don't know what the target class/package should be.  In this case you know the target class, so you should use an explicit intent.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184182

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to party, but recently i tried to do same thing and it worked used intent actions.

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction(Action_here);
```

so while registering intent use :-

```
registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, new IntentFilter(Action_here));
```

Worked for me.